# Redshift and without VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

*Please attach a message if this line of questioning is no longer appropriate for Stack and I will close / find a different forum.  It looks like there are similar questions posted, so I am going to post - but I do realize this is an evolving community.*

I am following this tutorial on launching a redshift sample cluster, so I can evaluate the product for usage:  [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-launch-sample-cluster.html]

I am step 3 - launch the cluster.  The tutorial suggests I do not need a VPC established  "**If you do not have a VPC, you will use the EC2-Classic platform to launch your cluster. Your screen will look similar to the following**".

my screen doesn't look exactly like that (perhaps there has been drift between the console and the tutorial).  The major difference is that the screen I see does not present a drop down for "**Cluster Parameter Group**" and where the VPC is selected it says "**Not in VPC**" and next to it there is the error message "**You must select a VPC. If you do not have one, please create one using the VPC console.**"

And I guess another problem is that the error message at the bottom of the screen reads: "**There was a problem fetching information required to launch: Not Authorized**" not allowing me to continue (which is expected).

Do I need to setup a VPC?  As I understand that isn't available on the free tier therefore...

[image]

Comment: That tutorial is from 2012 and appears to be outdated. It appears that you cannot run Redshift without a VPC now.

Comment: I suspected as much.  But I couldn't find any evidence on the web to that affect.

Comment: `Do I need to setup a VPC? As I understand that isn't available on the free tier` ... not sure where you're getting that info.   There isn't a charge for having a VPC -- they are just part of the service -- and new accounts should already have a pre-configured "Default" VPC present in each region.  [*"If you created your AWS account after 2013-12-04, it supports only EC2-VPC. In this case, you have a default VPC in each AWS region."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You require a VPC.

If no VPC appears in the list, go to the VPC console for that region and select **Actions -> VPCs -> Create Default VPC**.

If that option is not available, it is because your account is enabled for EC2-Classic in that region. In this case, return to the VPC Dashboard and **Start VPC Wizard** to create a VPC that matches your requirements (eg the second option that creates a public & private subnet).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not create the VPC
You need to check below details:

1) Make sure you provided all necessary information during signup. **Complete your AWS registration.**

2) **Check your email** to see if you have received any requests for additional information. If you have, please respond to those emails with the information requested.

3) Verify your **Credit/Debit** card information is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not create the VPC You need to check below details:

1) Make sure you provided all necessary information during signup. 
**Complete your AWS registration.**

2) **Check your email** to see if you have received any requests for additional information. If you have, please respond to those emails with the information requested.

3) **Verify your Credit/Debit card** information is correct.